# Load more posts with AJAX and also add pagination in URL

Tags: ajax, wordpress, pagination

On load more button, posts load without page load using AJAX, but wanted to implement Wordpress pagination on load more along with URL changing. Suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

```
    /* Category/tag page Masonry Grid */
    var $mgrid = $( '.post-grid' ).masonry();
    $mgrid.masonry( {
        itemSelector: '.post-outer',
    } );


    /* ------------------ Load More Posts Category/tag page ------------------ */       
    $( document ).on( 'click', '#post-button', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var offset = $( this ).attr( 'data-value' );
        var cat = $( this ).attr( 'data-cat' ); //load more button attribute
        var tag = $( this ).attr( 'data-tag' ); //load more button attribute
        var page = $( this ).attr( 'data-page' ); //load more button attribute
        var $content;
        $.ajax( {
            type: "post",
            async: false,
            dataType: "json",
            url: localizeObj.ajaxurl, //localize script in functions.php
            data: {
                action: 'fetch_posts', //ajax load more function in functions.php
                offset: offset,
                cat: cat,
                tag: tag,
                page: page,
                search_term: localizeObj.search_term,
                current_page: localizeObj.current_page
            },
            beforeSend: function() {
            },
            success: function(response) {
                /* Adding page numbers on ajax load more */
                var pathname = window.location.pathname;

                if ( response.success == 'yes' ) {
                    $content = $(response.posts);
                    $( '.post-masonry-grid' ).append( $content ).masonry( 'appended', $content );
                    page = parseInt(page) + 1;
                    offset = parseInt(offset) + 6;

                    $('.post-grid-outer').each( function() {
                        $('.post-grid-outer').addClass(offset);
                    });

                    $( '#post-grid-button' ).attr( 'data-value', offset );
                    $( '#post-grid-button' ).attr( 'data-page', page );

                    var page_num = '';
                    if(page <= 2) {
                        var page_num = 'page/'+ page;
                    } else { 
                        var page_num =  page;
                    }
                    window.history.pushState("URL", "Title", page_num); // Add page numbers to URL 

                } else {
                    $( '#post-button' ).hide();
                }
            },
            complete : function() {
            }
        } );
    } );
```